# Is ther any sensor enable simulator or emulator available in j2me?

Tags: java-me

Would you please help me to find out the sensor enabled emulators for j2me.
I would be heighly obliged if you help me for the same 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Samsung SDK with simulators
http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?cntsId=5181&platformId=3

Sony Ericcson SDK with simulators
http://developer.sonyericsson.com/getDocument.do?docId=99962